# discord.py waiting for multiple reactions

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make the bot say something for every green check mark reaction added. I have got the bot waiting for reactions however it only allows one reaction from one user where I want it for a reaction added it will do something current code;

```py
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def br(self, ctx):
        msg = await self.Nao.say('Please the reaction I have added.')
        await self.Nao.add_reaction(msg, '✅')
        res = await self.Nao.wait_for_reaction('✅')
```

However I want it to to allow multiple reactions instead of one user. So for every reaction added it will say {USER.MENTION} added a reaction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `wait_for_reaction` in a loop, so it can repeat. I also added a `check` to keep the bot from acknowledging its own reactions.

```
check = lambda reaction, user: client.user != user
while True:
    res = await self.Nao.wait_for_reaction(emoji='\N{WHITE HEAVY CHECK MARK}', message=msg, check=check)
    if res:
        await self.Nao.say(f"{res.user.mention} added a reaction!")
```

Comment: That is now returning "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'user'
"

Comment: Oops, we need to await `wait_for_reaction`

Comment: I have this working however, now. Once a reaction is added, it requires a message to be sent before it waits for another reaction. [code](https://hastebin.com/lugosonixu.sql)

Comment: You could try making a separate task to do whatever actions you need to do when someone reacts to the message, so this task gets back to waiting for reactions as soon as possible. https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks